# Natural Language Processing: Find obscenities in English?

Tags: java, nlp

Given a set of words tagged for part of speech, I want to find those that are obscenities in mainstream English. How might I do this? Should I just make a huge list, and check for the presence of anything in the list? Should I try to use a regex to capture a bunch of variations on a single root?

If it makes it easier, I don't want to filter out, just to get a count. So if there are some false positives, it's not the end of the world, as long as there's a more or less uniformly over exaggerated rate.

Comment: Before you do this, you might want to buttert that your buttumptions are correct. You don't want to embarrbutt yourself by implementing this poorly, causing your users to leave to the compebreastion.

Comment: yeah, that's why I'm not fi173r1ng anything out, just trying to count.

Comment: @Julian - Agreed - that would be a clbuttic mistake. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001176.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A huge list and think of the target audience. Is there 3rd party service that you can use that specialises in this rather than rolling your own?

Some quick thoughts:

- The [Scunthorpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_Problem) problem (and follow the links to "[Swear filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swear_filter)" for more)
- British or American English? fanny, fag etc
- Political correctness: "black" or "Afro-American"?

Edit:

- [Be very careful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22) and [again here](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/wales/901723.stm). Normal words can offend, whether by choice or ignorance

Comment: Here are some lists: http://fffff.at/googles-official-list-of-bad-words/ http://www.noswearing.com/dictionary

Answer (score 8):

Is the phrase  *[I want to stick my long-necked Giraffe up your fluffy white bunny](http://habitatchronicles.com/2007/03/the-untold-history-of-toontowns-speedchat-or-blockchattm-from-disney-finally-arrives/)* obscene?

Comment: How did I know you're a Brit before I looked at your profile... ;-)

Comment: I agree with the point that is so eloquently being made by this answer. A word itself is harmless until its intent is considered. Simple blanking or filtering of words is rarely a satisfactory way to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a huge list.

Regex'es have the problem of misfiring, when applied to natural language - especially with an amount of exceptions English has.

Comment: Huge lists of regular expressions might be better.  Suppose "nose" was a bad word - I could write it "n ose" or "n0se" or "noze" or "n0z3" or whatever, and you'd want to find it.  Having character classes like [0oO] and [sSzZ] is going to make the list much easier.

Comment: @David: and much more prone to errors. I've seen forums blocking legitimate words just because the authors have not realized that their regex actually captures something legitimate - and this was Russian, where such thing is much less likely than in English (less words differing by a single letter, say)

Comment: A regular expression is just another way if implementing a trie, which is just a more compact way of implementing a word list. You're going to have to balance between the Scunthorpe problem and character replacement attacks no matter what algorithm you use.

Comment: And there's no perfect solution. For example, you can buy nice writing implements from www.penisland.com, but God forbid you try to google "Pen Island"...

Answer (score 2):

Note that any NLP logic like this will be subject to attacks of "character replacement":

For example, I can write "hello" as "he11o", replacing L's with One's. Same with obscenities. So while there's no perfect answer, a "blacklist" approach of "bad words" might work. Watch out for false positives (I'd run my blacklist against a large book to see what comes up)

Answer (score 1):

One problem with filters of this kind is their tendency to flag entirely proper English town names like Scunthorpe. While that can be reduced by checking the whole word rather than parts, you then find people taking advantage by merging their offensive words with adjacent text.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your text source is, but I'd go for some kind of established and proven pattern matching algorithm, using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the morphy lemmatizer built into WordNet, and then determine whether the lemma is an obscenity. This will solve the problem of different verb forms, plurals, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would advocate a large list of *simple* regex's.  Smaller than a list of the variants, but not trying to capture anything more than letter alternatives in any given expression: like "f[u_-@#$%^&*.]ck".

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Bayesian Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) to solve this problem. Bayesian probability is a powerful technique used by spam filters to detect spam/phishing messages in your email inbox. You can train your analysis engine so that it can improve over time. The ability to detect a legitimate email vs. a spam email sounds identical to the problem you are experiencing.

Here are a couple of useful links:

[A Plan For Spam](http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html) - The first proposal to use Bayesian analysis to combat spam.

[Data Mining (ppt)](http://www.i-proving.ca/space/Lunch+and+Learns/Data+Mining+Strategies/Data+Mining+Lunch+and+Learn.ppt) - This was written by a colleague of mine.

[Classifier4J](http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/) - A text classifier library written in Java (they exist for every language, but you tagged this question with Java).

Comment: Naive Bayesian text classifiers don't really help with the problem of finding individual words in a document. Filtering obscenities out of a document (when presumably you want to keep the rest of the document) is very different from detecting whether the email as a whole has valuable content. Moreover, a lot of stuff will get through if you try to filter out swear words by blocking the whole email based on content.

Comment: The question states that there is no intention to 'filter out' anything; only to count the number of obscenities in text. One problem raised is that a word may or may not be an obscenity (depending on it's lexical context). Bayesian probability would be useful in determining whether a sentence (or a larger piece of text) contains profanity. Sentences that are found likely to contain profanity could then be fed into a separate algorithm responsible for counting each obscenity (so it is used as a filter, but only to locate text that has a high probability of being offensive).

Comment: I think lexiccal context is a lot less of an issue than you make it out to be, and would only add Bayesian classification to deal with the context if a purely word-list based approach didn't help. Even so, I wouldn't do it on sentences, rather I'd do it on a 5 to 10 word window around the lexeme in question.

Answer (score 0):

There are webservices that do this kind of thing in English.

I'm sure there are others, but I've used [WebPurify](http://www.webpurify.com/) in a project for precisely this reason before.

Answer (score 0):

At Melissa Data, when my manager , the director of Massachusetts Research and Development and I refactored a Data Profiler targeted at Relational Databases , we counted profanities by the number of Levinshtein Distance matches where the number of insertions, deletions and substitutions is tunable by the user so as to allow for spelling mistakes, Germanic equivalents of English language, plurals, as well as whitespace and non-whitespace punctuation. We speeded up the running time of the Levinshtein Distance calculation by looking only in the diagonal bands of the n by n matrix.