# Word blocklist in PHP keyword logging script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logging

I have a PHP script that logs queries on a search script into a MySQL database. However, If a query is put in for an inappropriate term I would not like it to be added to the database. I want a list of words that I deem to be inappropriate which is checked before adding the term to the database. How can I go about doing this?

My current PHP code is:

```
<?php

$query=$_GET['q'];

logQuery($query);
function logQuery($query){
$query="insert into queries (query) values ('$query') on duplicate key update value=value+1";
mysql_query($query);
}

?>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "inappropriate"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835605/natural-language-processing-find-obscenities-in-english/1835666#1835666

Comment: Users of your script can run arbitrary SQL on your database by using a query with an apostrophe in it. This is known as SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$inappropriate = array('clod', 'hipster');
if (!in_array($word, $inappropriate)) {
    // Add word to database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply prepare a list of bad words into an array and use the following code to replace such words with *****.

```
$badWords = array("badWord1", "badWord2", "badWord3", "badWord4", "badWord1");
$cleanUp = str_replace($badWords, "****", $originalString);
```

If you want to identify such words including its extensions (eg. ing, ed, s, ly, etc.) and respond with a message stating that it is inappropriate, You can do the following. Any how you should get the full list of such bad words to identify it.

```
// Array of Bad words
$words = array('badWord1','badWord2','badWord3','badWord14');
// Array of extention to words
$exten = array('','ed','ing','s');
// Input string
$str = 'this is a dam sentence';
// Create an array from input
$string = explode(' ',strtolower($str));
// Create a new array for all combinations of swear words
$wordList = array();
// Add all combinations to the new array
foreach($words as $word){
   foreach($exten as $ext){
      $wordList[] = $word.$ext;
   }
}
// Loop through each input word, and check if it is a bad word or not
// FALSE = Good Words
// TRUE = Bad Words
$badWord = FALSE;
foreach($string as $s){
   if(in_array($s, $wordList)){
      $badWord = TRUE;
   }
}
// Do something if output is good or bad in this case display a message
if($badWord)
   echo 'This input contains inappropriate content';
else
   echo 'This is valid input!';
```